# Determine joint density of expressions of two variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, density-function

I have two identically distributed and independent variables, $X$ and $Y$, on $(0, 1)$. I also have $U = X + Y$ and $V = X / Y$. The problem is to computer the joint density of $U$ and $V$. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: $X,Y$ are continuous, right? They have densities?

Comment: Yes, they are continuous.

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ were independent (I don't know) you could use that the joint density of two independent variables is just the product of the densities.

Comment: Really would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Let $\boldsymbol g(u, v) = (u v/(v + 1), u/(v + 1))$. Since $(X, Y) = \boldsymbol g(U, V)$, the [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables) formula gives
$$f_{U, V}(u, v) =
\left| \det \frac {\partial(x, y)} {\partial(u, v)} \right| f_{X, Y}(x, y),\\
(x, y) = \boldsymbol g(u, v).$$
Keep in mind that the pdf for uniformly distributed $X$ and $Y$ is $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = [0 < x < 1 \land 0 < y < 1]$, not $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 1$.

Comment: @Maxim is the equation involving the determinant there as simple as the joint density can be expressed given the problem? Or is there a way to simplify that further?

Comment: Sure you can simplify it. $\partial(x, y)/\partial(u, v)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\boldsymbol g$. $0 < u v/(v + 1) < 1 \land 0 < u/(v + 1) < 1$ can be simplified too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Assuming $X,Y$ are continuous on $(0,1)$.

Given $U,V$ you have $X = UV/(V+1)$ and $Y = U/(V+1)$.

Transform $\mathbb{P}[(U,V) \in A]$ to $\mathbb{P}(X,Y) \in B]$

**UPDATE**

So you have
$$
F_{UV}(u,v)
 = \mathbb{P}[U < u, V<v]
 = \mathbb{P}[X+Y < u, X<vY]
 = \iint_A f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy
$$
where $A$ is the region bounded by $0 < x,y < 1, x+y<u, x<vy$, and since $X,Y$ are independent, $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. Can you complete the problem now?

**UPDATE 2**

Your region is a triangle, bounded by the $y$-axis between the origin and $(0,u)$ from the left, the line $x+y = u$ from the top and the line $x = vy$ from the bottom. Hence the bounds of integration would be $x/v < y < u-x$ with $0 < x < uv/(v+1)$.

Let the pdf and cdf of $X$ and $Y$ be denoted by $g$ and $G$. Thus you have
$$
\begin{split}
F_{UV}(u,v)
 &= \int_{x=0}^{x=uv/(v+1)}
    \int_{y=x/v}^{y=u-x}
         g(x) g(y) dy dx \\
 &= \int_{x=0}^{x=uv/(v+1)}
       \left(G(u-x)- G\left( \frac{x}{v} \right)\right) g(x) dx
\end{split}
$$

If you know, for example, that $X,Y$ are uniform, then on $(0,1)$ we have $g(x) = 1$ and $G(x) = x$, so this integral becomes
$$
\begin{split}
F_{UV}(u,v)
 &= \int_{x=0}^{x=uv/(v+1)}
       \left((u-x)- \left( \frac{x}{v} \right)\right) 1 dx \\
 &= \frac{v u^2}{v+1} - \left(\frac{uv}{v+1}\right)^2 \frac{v+1}{2v} \\
 &= \frac{2vu^2 - u^2 v}{2(v+1)} \\
 &= \frac{vu^2}{2(v+1)}
\end{split}
$$
and $f_{UV}(uv)$ is the mixed partial of that as I wrote before.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on transformations. So I solve for X and Y, and then I'm able to express the densities of U and V in terms of X and Y? Is that it?

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books that's the basic idea, yes. For example for a 1-D transformation between $A$ and $B$ you have $$F_A(a) = \mathbb{P}[A < a] = \mathbb{P}[B < g(a)] = F_B(g(a))$$ which would implify by differentiation that $f_A(a) = F_A'(a) = f_B(g(a)) g'(a)$ or something like that

Comment: I've been trying to take what you have and run with it but I'm not sure what step to take past solving for X and Y. I haven't done probability transformations before.

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books please see the update

Comment: Thank you for the additional help. I understand how you get to the double integral, but am confused on how to integrate it. First, since I don't have the pdf of X,Y, do I just take the integral of that to be the cdf? After all it's not specified what distribution they are. Second, when having these boundaries on the integrals, how am I supposed to incorporate u and v into the integration, since they appear in the boundaries?

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books the trick is to set up the correct integration bounds on the integrals, that will incorporate $u$ and $v$. You cannot integrate it if you don't have a specific distribution, since changing the distribution will change the end result. However, you don't actually need $F_{UV}(u,v)$. Instead you need $$f_{UV}(u,v) = \frac{\partial^2 F_{UV}(u,v)}{\partial u \partial v}$$ which may be good enough to eliminate both integrals, using the fact the integrands are separable. The final result for $f_{UV}(u,v)$ will still depend on $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ though.

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books Since you are given that $X,Y$ have the same distribution, you have $f_X(\cdot) = f_Y(\cdot)$ so you can denote them by the same function...

Comment: I still don't understand how to do these sorts of problems. I have a lot of them I'm supposed to solve, without any guidance (having to work ahead in a course because of some unusualness with the schedule) and am just hoping for a full example of how to solve a problem like this so I can learn from it and do the rest.

Comment: @Andrew_Authors_Books see another update